# How to bind form using data-annotation to handle error check?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am bit struggling to handle error check using data-annotation. The issue i want to bind some fields as required with asterik(compulsory).Here is my logic to do this and need some help around it.
[image]

```
 [Required]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StreetAddressLine { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you have tried already and what error you get, it helps.

Comment: Basically what i want, is to do some validation when leaving the form@Html.TextBoxFor(). It must states error "This field is required".